# Possible to Return/Exit From ASP.Net Include?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, server-side-includes

If I have a parent file with an include:

```
' Parent.aspx
<!--#include virtual="/inc/MyInclude.aspx"-->
```

Is it possible *within MyInclude.aspx* to "return" or "exit" from the include? Something like:

```
' MyInclude.aspx
if someCondition then
    'exit include - in other words, don't process or render any more of it.

' Rest of include contents
...
...
...
```

I know I could just do an if/else like:

```
' MyInclude.aspx
if someCondition then
    'do nothing.
else
    ' Rest of include contents
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

But I simply want to avoid indenting all the contents of the include.

Comment: When includes are processed in ASP they are just seen as an extension of the existing page being processed there is no way to "step out" of them. You can however be clever the way you structure your include so it only runs the specific part you wish using a flag or some other approach.

Comment: Just notice the `aspx` reference which suggests you are using ASP.Net not Classic ASP. Fairly sure includes in ASP.Net behave the same way.

Comment: Oops - thanks, @Lankymart!